# Changing app language on the fly does not work with Base Internationalization

Tags: ios, objective-c, internationalization

For the attached little sample project, I use `Base Internationalization` feature to utilize one storyboard for two languages (English & Arabic).
In the project I have one `ViewController` in the storyboard with a `UILabel`, `UIImageView` and a `UIButton`, I want to localize this `ViewController` with a button tap, so the method that does language switching (in `AppDelegate`) is this:

```
NSArray* languages = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
NSString *currentLang = [languages objectAtIndex:0];

if([currentLang isEqualToString:@"en"]) { //change to arabic

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"ar"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
else { //change to english

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"en"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController;

self.window.rootViewController = vc;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

but the `ViewController` will not take the effect unless I restart the app, or do `exit(0)` to kill the app, and then relaunch it again.

**the question is: how can I switch the app's language without having to quit it and relaunch it ?**

the sample: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57066689/TestAutoLayout3.zip

thank you so much in advance.

p.s. I've read almost all related questions, but none resolve this scenario with a base storyboard.

Comment: Refer this http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2012/06/iphone-ipad-custom-language-settings.html